# SQL Server / TSQL Updating a table with a unique constraint

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design, stored-procedures

If I have two tables, say:

```
Clients
(
  ClientID int primary key,
  ClientName varchar(50) not null
)
```

and

```
Addresses
(
  AddressID int primary key,
  AddressLine1 varchar(50),
  etc..
  ClientID int not null,
  IsPrimaryAddress bit not null
)
```

with a unique constraint across `(ClientID, IsPrimaryAddress)`, how can up date those tables from a collection in code (not a single sql statement) without violating the constraint?

Thanks...

Comment: What does your collection look like? How are you transferring it to SQL? One problem with this constraint is that you will only be able to have 2 addresses per Client (one primary, one not).

Comment: Just don't try to insert anything that would violate the constraint?!?!? I don't really understand your question, I'm afraid.... what do you need to update on those tables?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a mistake to have a unique constraint across (ClientID, IsPrimaryAddress), unless you want to ensure that a client can have no more than two addresses (one primary, one other), as any time you try to add further non-primary addresses you will be violating the integrity constraint.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned already, the problem here seems to stem from having an overly restrictive unique constraint. Presumably this causes you difficulty when you have two addresses for a client and want to swap over which is the primary. In this case, you first update the primary address to be non-primary and immediately fail because two non-primary addresses for the same client violates the constraint.

The problem, therefore, would be fixed by only enforcing the unique constraint on ClientID when the address is primary. Such [conditional unique constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint) have been discussed on stack overflow before.

If you were using Oracle, then you can be clever and do something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_primary_addr ON Addresses (
  DECODE (IsPrimaryAddress, 1, ClientId, NULL));
```

But I'm assuming that you are using sql-server or something else, so you'll be forced to do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PrimaryAddressCount(@Id INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ret INT;
  SELECT @ret = COUNT(*) FROM Addresses WHERE ClientId = @Id AND IsPrimaryAddress = 1;
  RETURN @ret;
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE Addresses
  ADD CONSTRAINT SinglePrimaryConstraint
CHECK (IsPrimaryAddress != 1 OR dbo.PrimaryAddressCount(ClientId) = 1);
```

Either way, the resulting constraint will allow as many non-primary addresses as you like for each client, but will enforce a single primary address. This should enable you to update addresses easily, as long as you always write the new primary address last.