# Handle parallel identical insertion in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, stored-procedures, sql-insert

We are developing a Spring Boot application backed by a MySQL database and I have a question to which I couldn't find an answer, though there are several similar questions here on SO.
The problem is to keep only one insert in the database if there are several **parallel identical insert** statements ran.

For example, if my Entity has the attributes `(Id, parent_id and status)`, we don't want to allow more than one Entity with the `same parent_id and status = 1` - even though they come in this form from the client, which spams our endpoint with the same request. I know that other db vendors allow for something called **conditional** unique key, i.e. that is a unique key like `(parent_id, status = 1)`, but MySql does not. Is there any way to achieve this with an index, or even with Stored Procedures?

Similar questions (for reference):

1. [conditional unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint/5149263)
2. [SQL can I have a "conditionally unique" constraint on a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283347/sql-can-i-have-a-conditionally-unique-constraint-on-a-table)
3. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/function-based-index-as-a-conditional-unique-key
4. [Can I conditionally enforce a uniqueness constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293543/can-i-conditionally-enforce-a-uniqueness-constraint)
5. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a little trick.

include one more virtual persitant column with a IF() function.
this will be store the parent_id if the status = 1 else NULL
so you can create a UNIQUE KEY on this field

```
CREATE TABLE `cond` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cond_status` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(`status` = 1,`parent_id`,NULL)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_cond_status` (`cond_status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [Bernd]> select * from cond;
Empty set (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1234, 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1235, 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1235, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1235, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1235, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1235, 4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> INSERT INTO cond (parent_id,`status`) VALUES(1235, 1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1235' for key 'idx_cond_status'
MariaDB [Bernd]> 

MariaDB [Bernd]> select * from cond;
+----+-----------+--------+-------------+
| id | parent_id | status | cond_status |
+----+-----------+--------+-------------+
|  1 |      1234 |      0 |        NULL |
|  2 |      1235 |      0 |        NULL |
|  3 |      1235 |      2 |        NULL |
|  4 |      1235 |      2 |        NULL |
|  5 |      1235 |      1 |        1235 |
|  6 |      1235 |      4 |        NULL |
+----+-----------+--------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]>
```

NOTE: the create table is for MariaDB, but is nearly the same in MySQL

Comment: this looks like a good solution, but indeed seems a bit "hacky". While the payload is not verily increased, I have a real concern for how this kind of solution will scale in a production db with scores of columns. Are you aware of a solution using stored procedures, so the "state" remains the same and we only alter the "behaviour"?