# mySQL SELECT using a foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm having a hard time finding this answer so I'm hoping you guy can help me out.

I have two tables:

**event_list** with columns 'id', 'name', 'date' and **event_default** with one column 'default_id' which is a foreign key event_list('id')

The idea is that only one event can be default at a time, hence why event_default can only have one value (the id of the event in event_list).

I need a SELECT statement that obtains the event_list data of the event that is currently default. But I want to do this in one SELECT statement which I think I can do rather then two. I am using the PDO framework if that helps.

Success! Thank you. I ended up using:

```
$this->connection->query('SELECT * FROM event_list el JOIN event_default ef ON el.id = ef.default_id');
```

Comment: How do you select your default event in the event_default table? Does this table contain only one row?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4956023/283366) for some other ideas to implement what you're trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I don't get the requirements wrong, this would do it:

```
select el.data from event_list el
join event_default ef on el.id = ef.default_id
```

I assume the table `event_default` only contains one row in which you specify the default event. So, after joining with the `event_list` table you'll get only one row (if `id` is the PK of `event_list`).

Comment: What is the significance of "el.data", "el", "ef", "el.id"? Are they like labels/objects of the table names?

Comment: They are aliases. Instead of writing `event_list.id` I aliased that table so that I can reference that field as `el.id` (it's an L not a 1)

Comment: @MostyMostacho FYI, `data` doesn't appear to be part of the `event_list` columns (`id`, `name` and `date`)

Comment: @Phil: In the question that field is named `data` and also `date`:)

Comment: @MostyMostacho I think when the OP said *"event_list data"*, they meant all columns in that row, not specifically a `data` column

Comment: Oh, good point. Then just replacing `el.data` with `el.*` will do the trick, if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the parameter `WHERE` instead of `JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, etc.):

```
SELECT el.data 
    FROM event_list el, event_default ef 
    WHERE el.id = ef.default_id;
```

if there are more than two tables:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t2.field6, t2.field7
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 
    WHERE t1.field2 = t2.field3 AND t1.field4=t3.field5;
```

where there are three tables: `table1` with fields/columns `field1`, `field2`, `field4`;  `table2` with fields `field3`, `field6`; `table3` with fields `field5`, `field7`. If it is necessary one can use the same table names in `FROM` section and select any fields.

But `JOIN` is a litle bit faster and is recommended.