# SQL Server constraint on referenced columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  A_UNIQUE_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  A_OTHER_ID int NOT NULL,
  A_CURRENT_FL bit NOT NULL )
```

and it has values similar to this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A VALUES (1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO TABLE A VALUES (2, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO TABLE A VALUES (3, 1, 1);
```

I want to create another table B like this

```
CREATE TABLE B (
  B_UNIQUE_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  A_OTHER_ID int NOT NULL)
```

where `B.A_OTHER_ID` is constrained to a unique row in A. So `B.A_OTHER_ID = A.A_OTHER_ID AND A.CURRENT_FL = 1`. Is that possible with some type of check constraint setup? Examples are very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a "unique row in A"?  You want `B.A_OTHER_ID` to be unique AND reference `A.A_OTHER_ID`?  Or `A.A_OTHER_ID` allows duplicate values, and you don't want `B.A_OTHER_ID` to have more duplicates than are in the `A` table itself?  Can you provide some good, unambiguous examples of what should be valid according to this constraint, and what should be invalid?

Comment: A row in table A is essentially unique for any value of A.A_OTHER_ID when it has the A_CURRENT_FL set to 1, as there can only be one current record for each A.A_OTHER_ID. All other rows with the same A.A_OTHER_ID will have a value of 0 in the A_CURRENT_FL. I want TABLE B to be able to refer to the row that has A_CURRENT_FL set to 1, similar to a foreign key. The problem I have is that to be unique I need to combine A.A_OTHER_ID and an A.A_CURRENT_FL = 1, and I only want to refer to the distinct value of A.A_OTHER_ID in TABLE B. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with some computed columns, but it doesn't look very pretty:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  A_UNIQUE_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  A_OTHER_ID int NOT NULL,
  A_CURRENT_FL bit NOT NULL,
  OTHER_XREF as CASE WHEN A_CURRENT_FL = 1 THEN A_OTHER_ID END persisted,
  UNIQ as CASE WHEN A_CURRENT_FL = 0 THEN A_UNIQUE_ID ELSE 0 END persisted 
  constraint UQ_OTHER_XREF UNIQUE (OTHER_XREF,UNIQ)
  )

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE B (
  B_UNIQUE_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  A_OTHER_ID int NOT NULL,
  XREF as 0 persisted,
  constraint FK_B_A FOREIGN KEY (A_OTHER_ID,XREF) references A (OTHER_XREF,UNIQ))
```

This works:

```
  insert into B VALUES (2,1)
```

This breaks the FK constraint:

```
  insert into B VALUES (3,2)
```

The two computed columns in table A ensure that any row with `A_CURRENT_FL` = `1` has that as a distinct value in `OTHER_XREF`. Other rows will have `NULL` in that column. However, to apply a `UNIQUE` constraint (the target for the foreign key), we need something that will be distinctly different for every row with a `NULL`, whilst being a well-known value for the row with `A_CURRENT_FL` = `1`. In this case, I made the well known value `0`.

Finally, the foreign key constraint needs to match *both* of these columns, so we add a new computed column in table B with the well known value `0`.

Column names aren't particularly good, but I'm sure you can come up with some.

---

Note, also, that by the above, we've also implemented another constraint that you didn't mention, but that also may be important - there can't be two rows now in table A that both have `A_CURRENT_FL` set to 1, for the same `A_OTHER_ID` value. This also generates an error:

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES (4,1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK to start off you need a constraint on Table A to make it unique as you have described above. Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866100/345659) you could create a function and call that in your new check constraint.
eg:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Check_A_CURRENT_FL_Count(@Id INT) RETURNS INT AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ret INT;
  SELECT @ret = COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A_OTHER_ID = @Id AND A_CURRENT_FL = 1;
  RETURN @ret;
END
GO

alter table A add constraint [CK_A] CHECK (NOT (dbo.Check_A_CURRENT_FL_Count(A_OTHER_ID) > 1 AND A_CURRENT_FL = 1))
GO
```

Then if I'm understanding what you want correctly - you can use the same function in a check constraint on Table B. Not entirely sure what the purpose of this would be, although obviously you are using a contrived example. If you wanted a list of unique IDs from Table A - you could use A_OTHER_ID as the primary key in Table B, and get rid of B_UNIQUE_ID?