# In Postgresql, force unique on combination of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I would like to set up a table in PostgreSQL such that two columns together must be unique. There can be multiple values of either value, so long as there are not two that share both.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL
)
```

So, `col1` and `col2` can repeat, but not at the same time. So, this would be allowed (Not including the id)

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

but not this:

```
1 1
1 2
1 1 -- would reject this insert for violating constraints
```

Comment: As this is a top rank search result in google, Maybe better to provide alter exist table too

Answer (score 473, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (col1, col2)
)
```

`autoincrement` is not postgresql. You want a `integer primary key generated always as identity` (or `serial` if you use PG 9 or lower.  [`serial` was soft-deprecated in PG 10](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)).

If `col1` and `col2` make a unique and can't be null then they make a good primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2)
)
```

Comment: I like the suggestion of a primary key over unique here, because we do not allow NULL values in this case. From the PostgeSQL docs: "Note that a unique constraint does not, by itself, provide a unique identifier because it does not exclude null values.)" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2038

Comment: How can I implement this in schema definition?

Comment: In some scenarios you might want a surrogate key to be used as a primary key rather than a combination of columns. In particular to improve performance when doing joins on big data volumes. I personally went for the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT solution below.

Comment: Is it possible to enforce a unique constraint on just one permutation, such as unique(col1, col2 = '1')?

Comment: postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236365/postgresql-conditionally-unique-constraint
sql server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149263/5986661

Comment: But don’t sequential integers as primary keys outperform combinations as primary keys in indexing? Performance-wise.

Comment: Would this treat col 1 as and 2 as unique as well? Do I have to make each col and the combination unique to achieve this use case? In other words, I want col 1 to be unique,.and col 2 to be unique and lastly the combination be unique.

Comment: Not sure I understand @awm's question.  If col1 is unique, and col2 is unique, then col1+col2 is also unique, so there would be no need for a composite key or constraint.

Comment: I guess I meant combination in the mathematical sense such that the number of possible arrangements in the cols is unique  where the order of the selection does not matter. 
For example if A,B in col 1,2 then no other records should have A,B or B,A.

Answer (score 289):

Create unique constraint that two numbers together CANNOT together be repeated:

```
ALTER TABLE someTable
ADD UNIQUE (col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 44):

If, like me, you landed here with:

- a pre-existing table,
- to which you need to add a new column, and
- also need to add a new unique constraint on the *new* column as well as an *old* one, AND
- be able to undo it all (i.e. write a down migration)

Here is what worked for me, utilizing one of the above answers and expanding it:

```
-- up

ALTER TABLE myoldtable ADD COLUMN newcolumn TEXT;
ALTER TABLE myoldtable ADD CONSTRAINT myoldtable_oldcolumn_newcolumn_key UNIQUE (oldcolumn, newcolumn);

---

ALTER TABLE myoldtable DROP CONSTRAINT myoldtable_oldcolumn_newcolumn_key;
ALTER TABLE myoldtable DROP COLUMN newcolumn;

-- down
```

Answer (score 38):

Seems like regular UNIQUE CONSTRAINT :)

```
CREATE TABLE example (
a integer,
b integer,
c integer,
UNIQUE (a, c));
```

More [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-constraints.html)

Comment: Does this add an index for `a` and an index for `c` independently? Because I need to quickly find based on `a` sometimes, and quickly find based on `c` sometimes.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai This index on a,c internally serve for two types of queries.  A query with 'a' as where clause and a query with columns a and c present in the where clause will be benefited from the above index. In both ways, column 'a' should be present, as it's the look-up column.