# In postgresql, how can I make "name" unique only when "deleted" is false?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE "prm_project_service_product_and_services" (
  "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  "name" VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  "note" VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  "version" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_date" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_by_id" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
  "last_modified_date" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
  "last_modified_by_id" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
  "deleted" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT project_service_product_and_services_unique UNIQUE ("name")
);
```

I want to make `name` unique only when `deleted` is `false`, is this possible ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236365/postgresql-conditionally-unique-constraint). 
On an unrelated note, how would that work if deleted is turned back to true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a partial unique index:

```
create unique index punq_prm_project_service_product_and_services
    on prm_project_service_product_and_services(name)
    where not deleted;
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), this must be done with an index and not a unique constraint:

> A uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by creating a unique partial index.

Comment: Hi and thanks @GordonLinoff, Can't this be within the `CREATE` statement ?