# In Postgresql, add unique constraint on 2 columns, not equal to a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, multi-index

Have a table named `People`, column `address_id (int)` and `is_deleted (boolean)`, 
how can I add a unique constraint to allow unique `address_id` + `false`, and allow multiple `address_id` + `true`.

e.g.

```
address_id | is_deleted
-----------------------
1          | false
2          | true
2          | true
2          | true
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I add a unique constraint to allow unique address_id + false, and allow multiple address_id + true

Can't use a CHECK as that would not work in case of concurrent insertion or updates.

You can use a conditional unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX people_addr_id_is_deleted_unique 
ON People (address_id) WHERE (NOT is_deleted);
```

This unique index will only contain rows satisfying the specified WHERE condition. Depending on the percentage of matching rows, this may save a bit of storage space, or a lot relative to a full index. Also, updates on a row that is not included in a conditional index do not have to spend time updating the index.

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236365/postgresql-conditionally-unique-constraint). Also google "postgresql conditional unique constraint".