# How to add a constraint that's partial and also works with overlapping daterange for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, date-range

I am using a postgres with daterange field called `valid_period` in `thing_thing` table.

### The query I use to add the constraint

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE thing_thing 
ADD CONSTRAINT prevent_overlapping_valid_periods_by_team 
        EXCLUDE USING gist(team_id WITH =, valid_period WITH &&) 
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

This works well.

- row with same `team_id` and overlapping `valid_period` => blocked
- row with different `team_id` and overlapping `valid_period` => allowed ✅
- row with same `team_id` and NOT overlapping `valid_period` => allowed ✅

### What I need but not sure how to do

But I only want the constraint to kick in IF

- the field `is_removed` (a boolean field) is also false OR
- the field `state` (a varchar field) contains one of any possible values such as `CANCELLED`, `REJECTED`

So the following are not working:

- row with same `team_id` and overlapping `valid_period` but existing row `is_removed` is True => expected allowed ✅ but blocked
- row with same `team_id` and overlapping `valid_period` but existing row `state` is `CANCELLED` => expected allowed ✅ but blocked
- row with same `team_id` and overlapping `valid_period` but existing row `state` is `REJECTED` => expected allowed ✅ but blocked

How do I alter the constraints to allow the exceptions? In other words, a bit like partial unique index.

I am a bit pessimistic because I understand there's no such thing as a partial constraint from another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16236566/80353)

But at the same time, I think not possible to use partial unique index to prevent illegal overlapping daterange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a partial index with this - at least with PostgreSQL v13 you can - haven't checked the others yet.

Note the parentheses on the `WHERE` condition though - it protests if you forget those.

The example below is slightly simplified from your description, but logically the same.

```sql
=> CREATE TABLE teams (team_id int not null, valid_period daterange not null, is_removed boolean not null, state char not null);

=> ALTER TABLE teams ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlaps 
    EXCLUDE USING gist(team_id WITH =, valid_period WITH &&)
    WHERE (is_removed = false OR state IN ('C','R'));

=> INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, daterange('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'), false, 'X');
INSERT 0 1

=> INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, daterange('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'), false, 'X');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "no_overlaps"
DETAIL:  Key (team_id, valid_period)=(1, [2020-01-01,2021-01-01)) conflicts with existing key (team_id, valid_period)=(1, [2020-01-01,2021-01-01)).

=> INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, daterange('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'), true, 'X');
INSERT 0 1

=> INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, daterange('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'), true, 'C');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "no_overlaps"
DETAIL:  Key (team_id, valid_period)=(1, [2020-01-01,2021-01-01)) conflicts with existing key (team_id, valid_period)=(1, [2020-01-01,2021-01-01)).
```

Comment: Thank you, Richard. I am using postgres 10. I will check if it works there. By the way, I check the docs for 13 but I cannot find the docs stating what you said was explicitly possible. either at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertable.html or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-constraints.html if you do know where it exists at the docs can point for me? I want to learn what the docs say about this if possible

Comment: thank you, it does work in postgres 10 as well. I am surprised by the SO answer I found that says this is conditional constraints are not possible. Weird.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it was possible or not, so checked `\h alter table` in psql (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) and saw in the `table_constraint` section `EXCLUDE ... index_parameters [ WHERE ( predicate ) ]`. Good to know it's been supported for a few versions. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanna say that I still find that page hard to read... maybe it’s me ‍♂️

Comment: Sorry I realized the constraint will also block if I change existing rows. Was wondering if you have a solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64586618/update-existing-row-in-postgres-table-that-uses-exclude-constraints-to-avoid-ove