# Conditional UNIQUE constraint on table?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint, exclusion-constraint

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE mitg.tbl_gch_customers (
    pe character varying(10)NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    city character varying,
    address character varying  NOT NULL,
    state character varying,
    zip character varying ,
    country character varying,
    phone character varying,
    "primary" character(1) NOT NULL
)
```

How can I add a constraint to ensure that a unique row is defined as unique `pe` "identifier" AND `"primary"` = 'Y'? In other words, a `"primary"` customer row can only have one flagged 'Y' for each `pe` number.  But this constraint must allow multiple `"primary"` = 'N' customers with same `pe` number.

Comment: Do this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236365/postgresql-conditionally-unique-constraint is the problem solved with ```CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_pe_for_primary_customer ON mitg.tbl_gch_customers (pe) WHERE ("primary"='Y');``` ?

Comment: Aside: "primary" should really not be used as column name, being a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). And the type should probably be `boolean` instead of `char(1)`.