# Add a deferrable unique constraint with a check

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I would like to add a deferrable unique constraint with a check, such as

```sql
ALTER TABLE locations 
   ADD CONSTRAINT short_name 
    UNIQUE (hallway, row, module, level, position, zone_id) 
    CHECK (active) DEFERRABLE
```

But it is not possible.

Context: I have a table in which a given combination of fields must be unique, just when the field active is set on true (Possible CHECK?). Normally we receive a list of updates that must be performed as an atomic transaction, that is why the constraint must be deferrable.

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236365/postgresql-conditionally-unique-constraint) shows as an option one UNIQUE INDEX, but it is not deferrable.

Is there any possible solution or workaround?

Comment: You can't combine a UNIQUE constraint and a CHECK constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Exactly that is my question, which workarounds exist?

Comment: The only possibility is a deferred constraint trigger with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.