# PostgreSQL disallow having more than one row satisfying the condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `orders` with the columns: `id`, `user_id` and `status`. The `status` column is enum with values: pending, in_process, completed, declined.

I need to disallow a user to have more than one order with `status in (pending, in_process)`.

For example, having the table:

| id | status | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 1 |
| 2 | in_process | 1 |
| 3 | pending | 2 |

We shouldn't be able to insert neither one more order with status `pending` nor with status `in_process` for the `user_id=1`.

I feel like I should use an exclusion constraint here, but don't know how to disallow intersection of two sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking for an exclusion constraint here (as you want to allow any number of `completed` rows which all have the same values for `user_id` and `status`) but rather for a [conditionally unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16236365/1048572) - which postgres does not support as a `CONSTRAINT`, but you can use a [partial `UNIQUE` index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_active_order
ON orders (user_id)
WHERE (status IN ('pending', 'in_process'));
```

or

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_active_order
ON orders (user_id)
WHERE (status NOT IN ('completed','declined'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html). Since `status` is an enum you will, most likely, have to type cast the array.

```
create unique index on orders (user_id, status)
where status = any ( array['pending', 'in_process']::status_enum[] );
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but with this solution a user can have one order with status "pending" and one order with status "in_process".

Answer (score 0):

[Belayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75893451/5298879) and [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75893462/5298879) beat me to posting the partial unique approach, so for sports: you *can* make an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) work for this. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3mdnKXAT)

```sql
create type status_enum as enum('pending','in_process','completed','declined');

create table orders (
   id smallserial primary key,
   user_id int,
   status status_enum default 'pending',
   exclude (user_id with =) where (status in ('pending','in_process') ) 
);

insert into orders (status,user_id) values
('completed', 1),
('in_process',1),
('pending',   2);
--INSERT 0 3
insert into orders (user_id,status) values (1,'pending');
--ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "orders_user_id_excl"
--DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) conflicts with existing key (user_id)=(1).
insert into orders (user_id,status) values (1,'in_process');
--ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "orders_user_id_excl"
--DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) conflicts with existing key (user_id)=(1).
insert into orders (user_id,status) values (1,'declined');--no problem
--INSERT 0 1
```

Among those `where status in ('pending','in_process')`, no two `user_id`'s can be the same.

I said this is *for sports* because it can work, but offers no benefits over the [partial unique](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html):

> [Although it's allowed, there is little point in using B-tree or hash indexes with an exclusion constraint, because this does nothing that an ordinary unique constraint doesn't do better.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)