# How to Lock a PostgreSQL Table for Insert Until a Specific State is Reached?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with the following columns:

- `process_id` (not unique)
- `state` (pending, completed, failed)
- `timestamp`

Each time a process executes something, a record is inserted into the table with the state initially set to `pending` and the state is changed to `completed` when the process execution completes. I want to ensure that the table is locked for inserting records until the `process_id` reaches the `completed` state, and the lock is released at that point.

Here are the specifics of what I'm trying to achieve:

When a new record is inserted into the table, it should be blocked from insertion until the state changes from `pending` to `completed` for the corresponding `process_id`.
The table should allow multiple processes to insert records with different `process_id` values concurrently, but it should block any new insertions for a specific `process_id` until the state changes to `completed` for that process.
Once the state changes to `completed` for a `process_id`, any pending insertions for the same `process_id` should be allowed again.

Comment: You can do this with a partial unique indes, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16236566/585411.

Comment: I want the query to wait and not to throw error.

Comment: Then catch and handle the error. Still, this is the best solution.

Comment: @Nameless If the row exists in a table, you can also `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. That will block inside of PostgreSQL. Be careful in overusing this technique - it is easy to create deadlocks.