# Sql Data Modelling

Tags: sql, database-design, database-relations

[image]

Im attempting to build a database (pictured)

One of the criteria is that any instrument that is used can only be used by 1 musician at a time.

I was wondering how I would implement that it such a schema?

Another criteria is that 1 of the musicians on each song is the producer. How would I implement that criteria so that the producer has to come from the list of the musicians on that song?

Maybe this is 2 unrelated questions, I'm not sure?

Comment: Suggestion not related to the question (since it is answered):Don't use plural names for tables.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

If you merge the songinstruments and songmusicians table like this:
songinstrumentsmusicians:

```
SongId
InstrumentId
MusicianId
```

and add a unique constraing for (SongId,IntrumentId)

Second question:

Add a producer flag to songmusicians (or songinstrumentsmusicians).

Answer (score 0):

1st Question:
along the lines that @lajos-veres was heading down:

Create a table: MuscicianInstrument

PK|ID

FK|MusicianID | int

FK|InstrumentID | inn

Endate | datetime

Following this: ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint))
(This is assuming SQL Server)

Create a custom check function and check constraint:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckActiveCount(
 @MusicianId INT, @InstrumentId INT
) RETURNS INT AS BEGIN

  DECLARE @ret INT;
  SELECT @ret = COUNT(*) FROM MusicianInstrumnet 
     WHERE MusicianId = @MusicianId AND InstrumentId = @InstrumentId and (Enddate IS NULL  OR Endate > CURDATE());
  RETURN @ret;

END;
GO

ALTER TABLE MusicianInstrumnet
  ADD CONSTRAINT CheckActiveMusicianInstrument CHECK (NOT (dbo.CheckActiveCount(MusicianId, InstrumentId) > 1));
GO
```

Have to run, will try to tackle #2 after an exam.