# Allow some combination in sql

Tags: sql

I am working on one major issue where I have to add some constraint or need a way by which only this combination is allowed.

Table User (Strind id, String status)
[image: User Table primary key Id String Status Integer 1 id1 1 Allowed 2 id1 0 Allowed 3 id1 0 Allowed 4 id1 1 not Allowed as row 1 already exist]

only single id is allowed with value status 1. How can i write the constraint or how to solve this issue.
**mysql database**
Thanks,
Hasnain

Comment: You should add which RDBMS you're working with~

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint) will work with your requirements?